# Cannot store value inside .get method from npm library 'Sqlite3'

Tags: node.js, sqlite

**Problem:** I cannot get a variable into the correct scope, using the .get function from the nodejs library 'sqlite3'.

**Explanation:** Even though I have declared the variable 'image_path' in a scope from which it can be returned out of the function, when I assign it a value within the .get method, the scope of image_path appears to change; It is no longer able to be returned from the function 'returnImagePath' as expected.

**Aim:** I simply want to create a function with which I can query an Sqlite3 database using nodejs and return a value. If there is a better way of doing that then what I am currently trying, I will accept it as an answer.

**Example:**

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');

var dataBaseFile = 'test.db';
var dataBase = new sqlite3.Database(dataBaseFile);

function returnImagePath(id){
    var image_path;
    dataBase.serialize(function(){
        var statementReturnImagePath = dataBase.prepare(`SELECT image_path FROM images WHERE id = ${id}`);
        statementReturnImagePath.run();
        statementReturnImagePath.finalize();
        dataBase.get(`SELECT image_path FROM images WHERE id = 1`, function(error, row){
            image_path = row.image_path; 
            console.log(image_path); //image_path is defined here, and logs as expected
        });
        dataBase.close();
    });
    console.log(image_path); //image_path is undefined here
    return image_path;
}
var asdf = returnImagePath(1);
console.log(asdf); //this, therefore doesn't work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the node.js world, you have to understand what is asynchronous function.
If a process requires IO operations, you cannot just return the data from that process, instead you have to "wait" for the data.
We usually achieve this with a callback function.

Here is the example for you,

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');

var dataBaseFile = 'test.db';
var dataBase = new sqlite3.Database(dataBaseFile);

//callback is a function which accept (err, data)
function returnImagePath(id, callback){
    dataBase.serialize(function(){
        dataBase.get('SELECT image_path FROM images WHERE id = ' + id, function(error, row){
            if (error) {
                //stop and return error if error occurs
                return callback(error, null);
            }
            image_path = row.image_path; 
            console.log(image_path); //image_path is defined here, and logs as expected
            //now you get the image path and return it with callback
            callback(null, image_path);
            dataBase.close();
        });
    });
}
returnImagePath(1, function(err, image_path) {
    if (err) { //capture error(s)
        return console.error(err);
    }
    console.log(image_path); //now you get the image path
});
```

Comment: Thank you. The hardest thing about learning node.js for me has been understanding it's asynchronous nature. After I few read throughs this makes sense now :).